# hue 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 35-36: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: hive, hue

I run a sql in hue:

```
insert into Student values('01' , '赵雷' , '1990-01-01' , '男');
```

hue show:
'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 35-36: character maps to

[hue execption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypie7.png)

when i run :

```
select * from mydb.Student
```

[hue show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqzi5.png)

I try set hue.ini -> [desktop] ->default_site_encoding=utf-8
but it doesn't work.

and i try :
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
vim sitecustomize.py

```
# encoding=utf8
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

my python version is 2.7.5
restart hue, it doesn't work.

help! thks.

Comment: Please just search for that error message online. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, don't post images of text, post the text instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Answer (score 0):

hue version is 4.8.0

mysql version is 5.7
create table sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `Student` (
  `s_id` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `s_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `s_birth` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `s_sex` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`s_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```